# codigo no Modifica la BD postgresql y php

Tags: php, postgresql

Estoy tratando de modificar los datos de un usuario guardado en la base de datos, mas o menos creo que el codigo seria asi, soy nuevo en esto segun los video que e visto llegue a esto, no se si tenga un error solo no me modifica, cuando corro el html me dice que no se pudieron modificar revisp la bd y efectivamente no modifico

```
<?php

$conex = pg_connect ("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=prueba user=***** password=*****");
if(trim($_POST["cod_emp"]) != "")
{
 $cod_emp = strtolower(htmlentities($_POST["cod_emp"], ENT_QUOTES));
 $result = pg_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_empleado WHERE cod_emp=\''.$cod_emp.'\'');
}
$v_cod_emp=$_POST["cod_emp"];
  $v_cedula="'".$_POST["cedula"]."'";
  $v_nom_emp="'".$_POST["nom_emp"]."'";
  $v_ape_emp="'".$_POST["ape_emp"]."'";
  $v_fec_nac_emp="'".$_POST["fec_nac_emp"]."'";
  $v_estatus="'".$_POST["estatus"]."'";
  $v_fec_ing_emp="'".$_POST["fec_ing_emp"]."'";
  $v_id_estado="'".$_POST["id_estado"]."'";
  $v_id_cargo="'".$_POST["id_cargo"]."'";
  $v_id_division="'".$_POST["id_division"]."'";
  $v_id_municipio="'".$_POST["id_municipio"]."'";
  $v_id_parroquia="'".$_POST["id_parroquia"]."'";
  $v_tel_hab_emp="'".$_POST["tel_hab_emp"]."'";
  $v_tel_cel_emp="'".$_POST["tel_cel_emp"]."'";
  $v_mail_emp="'".$_POST["mail_emp"]."'";
  $v_id_rol="'".$_POST["id_rol"]."'";
  $v_password="'".$_POST["password"]."'";
  $v_id_oficina="'".$_POST["id_oficina"]."'";
  $v_ciudad_emp="'".$_POST["ciudad_emp"]."'";
  $v_calle_emp="'".$_POST["calle_emp"]."'";
  $v_edf_emp="'".$_POST["edf_emp"]."'";
  $v_piso_emp="'".$_POST["piso_emp"]."'";
  $v_apt_emp="'".$_POST["apt_emp"]."'";



   $sql= "UPDATE tbl_empleado SET cedula='$v_cedula', nom_emp='$v_nom_emp', ape_emp='$v_ape_emp', fec_nac_emp='$v_fec_nac_emp', estatus='$v_estatus', fec_ing_emp='$v_fec_ing_emp', id_cargo='$v_id_cargo', id_division='$v_id_division', id_estado='$v_id_estado', id_municipio='$v_id_municipio', id_parroquia='$v_id_parroquia', tel_hab_emp='$v_tel_hab_emp', tel_cel_emp='$v_tel_cel_emp', mail_emp='$v_mail_emp', id_rol='$v_id_rol', password='$v_password', id_oficina='$v_id_oficina', ciudad_emp='$v_ciudad_emp', calle_emp='$v_calle_emp', edf_emp='$v_edf_emp', piso_emp='$v_piso_emp', apt_emp='$v_apt_emp' WHERE cod_emp='$v_cod_emp'";
  $result = pg_Exec($conex, $sql);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de manera más sencilla. Mira

```php
<?php

$fields = array('cod_emp','cedula', 'nom_emp', 'ape_emp', 'fec_nac_emp', 'estatus', 'fec_ing_emp', 'id_estado','id_cargo',  'id_division', 'id_municipio','id_parroquia',  'tel_hab_emp', 'tel_cel_emp', 'mail_emp', 'id_rol', 'password', 'id_oficina', 'ciudad_emp', 'calle_emp', 'edf_emp', 'piso_emp', 'apt_emp');

$conex = pg_connect ("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=prueba user=***** password=*****");

if(trim($_POST["cod_emp"]) != "")
{
 $cod_emp = strtolower(htmlentities($_POST["cod_emp"], ENT_QUOTES));
 $result = pg_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_empleado WHERE cod_emp=\''.$cod_emp.'\'');
}

$data = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($fields) );
$data = array_map('pg_escape_string', $data);

$set = '';
foreach($data as $field => $value) {
  $set .= "{$field} = '{$value}',";
}


$sql= "UPDATE tbl_empleado SET ".rtrim($set, ',')." WHERE cod_emp= ".$data['cod_emp'];

  $result = pg_Exec($conex, $sql);
```

#### Explicación

Lo que hace esta solución es guardar todos los campos que se van a usar en el array `$fields`:

```php
$fields = array('cod_emp','cedula', 'nom_emp', 'ape_emp', 'fec_nac_emp', 'estatus', 'fec_ing_emp', 'id_estado','id_cargo',  'id_division', 'id_municipio','id_parroquia',  'tel_hab_emp', 'tel_cel_emp', 'mail_emp', 'id_rol', 'password', 'id_oficina', 'ciudad_emp', 'calle_emp', 'edf_emp', 'piso_emp', 'apt_emp');
```

Luego, se obtienen los datos del formulario correspondientes a estos campos y los asegura:

```php
$data = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($fields) );
$data = array_map('pg_escape_string', $data);
```

Se formatea la parte `set` de la consulta SQL:

```php
$set = '';
foreach($data as $field => $value) {
  $set .= "{$field} = '{$value}',";
}
```

Finalmente, se forma la consulta completa y se ejecuta:

```php
$sql= "UPDATE tbl_empleado SET ".rtrim($set, ',')." WHERE cod_emp= ".$data['cod_emp'];

$result = pg_Exec($conex, $sql);
```

Comment: Tu código no cubre la seguridad. La consulta queda vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: Muchas gracias me salvas :D  si ya le aprego lo de la vulnerabilidad :D eejejjej ya llevaba dos dias dándole

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que `pg_Exec` no existe, lo que ejecutaría una consulta preparada sería `pg_execute`, pero aquí no te funcionará, porque primero tendrías que preparar la consulta.

Además, esta parte del código no parece tener ninguna utilidad:

```
if(trim($_POST["cod_emp"]) != "")
{
 $cod_emp = strtolower(htmlentities($_POST["cod_emp"], ENT_QUOTES));
 $result = pg_query('SELECT * FROM tbl_empleado WHERE cod_emp=\''.$cod_emp.'\'');
}
```

Te propongo esta solución que implementa un código controlado y seguro. He puesto comentarios en algunas partes tratando de explicar lo que se hace. Si tienes alguna duda puedes preguntar en la parte de comentarios, debajo de esta respuesta.

```
<?php
    if ( $conex = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=prueba user=***** password=*****") ) {
        #Consulta preparada usando marcadores $ seguidos de un número secuencial
        $sql= "UPDATE tbl_empleado SET
            cedula=$1,
            nom_emp=$2,
            ape_emp=$3,
            fec_nac_emp=$4,
            estatus=$5,
            fec_ing_emp=$6,
            id_cargo=$7,
            id_division=$8,
            id_estado=$9,
            id_municipio=$10,
            id_parroquia=$11,
            tel_hab_emp=$12,
            tel_cel_emp=$13,
            mail_emp=$14,
            id_rol=$15,
            password=$16,
            id_oficina=$17,
            ciudad_emp=$18,
            calle_emp=$19,
            edf_emp=$20,
            piso_emp=$21,
            apt_emp=$22
         WHERE cod_emp=$23";
        #Controlamos que no hay error en la preparación 
        if ( $stmt=$pg_prepare($conex, "update_empleado", $sql) ) {
            #Si no hay error, pasamos a obtener las variables del POST
            $v_cod_emp=$_POST["cod_emp"];
            $v_cedula=$_POST["cedula"];
            $v_nom_emp=$_POST["nom_emp"];
            $v_ape_emp=$_POST["ape_emp"];
            $v_fec_nac_emp=$_POST["fec_nac_emp"];
            $v_estatus=$_POST["estatus"];
            $v_fec_ing_emp=$_POST["fec_ing_emp"];
            $v_id_estado=$_POST["id_estado"];
            $v_id_cargo=$_POST["id_cargo"];
            $v_id_division=$_POST["id_division"];
            $v_id_municipio=$_POST["id_municipio"];
            $v_id_parroquia=$_POST["id_parroquia"];
            $v_tel_hab_emp=$_POST["tel_hab_emp"];
            $v_tel_cel_emp=$_POST["tel_cel_emp"];
            $v_mail_emp=$_POST["mail_emp"];
            $v_id_rol=$_POST["id_rol"];
            $v_password=$_POST["password"];
            $v_id_oficina=$_POST["id_oficina"];
            $v_ciudad_emp=$_POST["ciudad_emp"];
            $v_calle_emp=$_POST["calle_emp"];
            $v_edf_emp=$_POST["edf_emp"];
            $v_piso_emp=$_POST["piso_emp"];
            $v_apt_emp=$_POST["apt_emp"];

            #Array con las variables para pasarlo luego en pg_execute
            $mParams=[
                        $v_cod_emp,
                        $v_cedula,
                        $v_nom_emp,
                        $v_ape_emp,
                        $v_fec_nac_emp,
                        $v_estatus,
                        $v_fec_ing_emp,
                        $v_id_estado,
                        $v_id_cargo,
                        $v_id_division,
                        $v_id_municipio,
                        $v_id_parroquia,
                        $v_tel_hab_emp,
                        $v_tel_cel_emp,
                        $v_mail_emp,
                        $v_id_rol,
                        $v_password,
                        $v_id_oficina,
                        $v_ciudad_emp,
                        $v_calle_emp,
                        $v_edf_emp,
                        $v_piso_emp,
                        $v_apt_emp
                     ];
            if ( $stmt = pg_execute($conex, "update_empleado", $mParams) ){
                $msg="Se actualizaron {pg_num_rows($stmt)} fila(s)";
            } else {
                $msg="Error en la ejecución: {pg_result_error($stmt)}";
            }
        } else {
            $msg="Error en la preparación: {pg_result_error($stmt)}";
        }
    } else {
        $msg="Error: No hay conexion";
    }
    echo $msg;
?>
```

Comment: okok, voy a probar muchas gracias por los consejos

Comment: @José si hay algún problema, error o duda sobre el código puedes preguntar en comentario. Saludos.